# TensorBoard Projector - Plotting Activation values rather than Variables possible?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to plot activation values in the Tensorboard Projector?

My use case is something like this:

```
input = tf.placeholder()
embedding_var = tf.contrib.layers.linear(input, ...(

embedding_config = projector.ProjectorConfig()     
embedding_obj = embedding_config.embeddings.add()                                                                                                                
embedding_obj.tensor_name = embedding_var.name  
...
```

But this not appear to work, it hangs on loading the data: [Tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZTiE.png)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!